# No response when using WebClient.UploadFile

Tags: c#, ftp, webclient

I'm uploading a file using the UploadFile method on the WebClient object. When the file is uploaded I would like to get a confirmation and according to MSDN (and also here on stackoverflow: [Should I check the response of WebClient.UploadFile to know if the upload was successful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451219/should-i-check-the-response-of-webclient-uploadfile-to-know-if-the-upload-was-su)) I should be able to read the returned byte array but that is always empty.

Am I doing something the wrong way?

```
WebClient FtpClient = new WebClient();
FtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("test", "test");
byte[] responseArray = FtpClient.UploadFile("ftp://localhost/Sample.rpt", @"C:\Test\Sample.rpt");
string s = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray);
Console.WriteLine(s); //Empty string
```

Or is it always successful if it doesn't return an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to myself: I couldn't make any sense of it so i switched to edt ftp (http://www.enterprisedt.com/) instead.